# Conditional formatting on cell value

Tags: c#, gridview, formatting, conditional-statements

I've been researching conditional formatting for GridViews all over the place, but I am new to ASP.Net and having a hard time.  This is the code that I've found that makes the most sense to me:

```
protected void GridviewRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
        if (CellValue >= 0)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        if (CellValue < 0)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

The GridView is incredibly simple: a header row and three columns with one row under the header with a currency amount in each column.  I just need the data cell on that second row, third column to be green if >=0 and red if <0.

I am getting an incorrect format on the int CellValue = line.

Comment: This sure looks right, what's happening, it's not working?

Comment: what is the value of e.Row.Cells[2].Text? Is it null? does Row.Cells[2] exist? Is it null? Since that is the line you're having trouble with, break down that line.

Comment: when using Convert.ToInt32() zero is returned if the value is null.

Comment: could you provide the message for the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: It provides the error FormatException was unhandled by user code. Input string was not in a correct format. And there is a value there.  It is the difference in columns one and two of the same gridview

Comment: @Jake you have a bad value in there so it's probbly coming through as empty. What is the value? See @Charles's comment below

Comment: @Jake: Please delete the "new" question and code from here and post as a new question as it's not related to "Conditional Formatting On Cell Value C#"

Comment: @Jake: You'll get better exposure to your particular problem that way. People don't tend to check questions marked as answered to provide more answers! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing your `int CellValue =` line with below one

```
int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Difference"));
```

Ref: 
http://www.johnchapman.name/asp-net-c-change-gridview-cell-background-color-based-on-value/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx

Comment: Priyank, if you're still around, do you have a quick answer to the second part of the original post (now that I've edited it) about Export to Excel?  I'm sure binding the data conflicts, but if you know a quick fix, I'd appreciate it.  Or anybody for that matter?

Comment: @Jake, why do you need to rebind it in export function? Here is any example that may help http://forums.asp.net/t/1255489.aspx

Comment: @Priyank, it was as simple as removing the second databind.  Thank you for putting me on to that.  Thanks for all your help today.

Comment: @Priyank, I lied.  That actually didn't fix it.  It seemed to work once, but is not working now.

Comment: @Priyank, I read through the resource you posted, but that seems to refer to exporting a single gridview, but I have to export 4 different gridviews into one Excel sheet.  I know that functionality works as written above, but somehow a conflict was created when I worked through all this conditional formatting business

Answer (score 1):

I would use int.TryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32, and verify that your text is actually numeric. If it looks correct, a likely candidate is that the text contains spaces.

Since your negative numbers are formatted like so ($1,000.00). Check your string for the existance of parenthesis, and you can format the color based on that

```
if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text.Contains(")")) {
  e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
} else {
  e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

or better yet

```
e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.Contains(")") ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

Comment: an easy way to identify the text is to set a breakpoint at that line and examine the value of e.Row.Cells[2].Text in the Watch debugging window.

Comment: this is only helpful if he has a default action to take if the value is incorrect. As far as your comment, hopefully he can get that done and get back to us.

Comment: The watch debugging window has the value as 0 when the code breaks.  The value should be $-92,316

Comment: @Jake What about the other cells? Do they have the correct values?

Comment: @Jake what has a value of 0, the CellValue or e.Row.Cells[2].Text ? Of course CellValue will have 0 because thats what int's default to also you need to check the value AFTER that line executes. You really want to see what r.Row.Cells[2].Text is, not CellValue.

Comment: I'll be honest, again very new to all this, but when I would debug and run the table before I tried to put in this formatting at all, all three cells had the correct values.  Now, I don't know since the page doesn't load on the debug, it just jumps back to Visual Studio with the line highlighted and the error.  How would I tell if they are registering correctly? (Don't know why they wouldn't, this code shouldn't change their values from SQL)

Comment: @Jake do this: string tmp = e.Row.Cells[2].Text; right before the line you have problems with now. Then, when you hit the break point tell us what the value os tmp is

Comment: @DustinDavis, I was referring to CellValue having the 0.  I see what you mean, but not sure how to view the other values.  One issue is that the page I'm working with requires session parameters from an earlier page, so I'm not sure how to do step into like I would in VBA, etc.

Comment: os tmp is "($95,168.17)" which is exactly what I need it to be.  (My -92,316 earlier was a ballpark guess).

Comment: @Jake thats why, you have $ and , in there. strip those out and you're good to go. Parsing is going to fail if it has those charactors

Comment: @Jake, if you are using () to identify negative numbers, then you can just check for the parenthesis foo.Contains("(") to determine if the value is negative. If you strip out the dollar sign, parenthesis and commas, the value will always be positive.

Comment: @Charles, what's the best way to check for a negative sign?  It looks like for now, the numbers are coming out in ()s if negative, which is fine.  What would the code to check for it be?

Comment: @Jake e.Row.Cells[2].Text.IndexOf('-') > -1

Comment: @DustinDavis - his text for negative numbers does not contain a minus sign, it has parenthesis (common in accounting).

Comment: @DustinDavis, where would that fit in?  And if the negatives are being represented by (), so I replace the '-' with '(' ?

Comment: @Charles either way, he can use indexOf() to determine if there is a parenthesis or a minus.

Comment: @Jake - yes just replace - with  (

Comment: @Titan, where in the code does it go?  Does it replace the int CellValue = line?  Or replace the IFs?

Comment: @Jake i've updated my answer with an example. It's better to use a bool and then change your IFs to check if the value is true or false. If(CellValue == true) { //Do green } else { //Do red }

Comment: @DustinDavis doh you beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid charactors in your values. Strip them out and you are good to go

```
int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text.Replace("$","").Replace(",","").Replace(".",""));
```

There might be a better way, but try that for now

Edit: Either update to my changes above or use double.Parse()

Edit:

```
int CellValue = (e.Row.Cells[2].Text.IndexOf('(') > -1) ? 0 : -1;
```

Better if you used a bool

```
bool CellValue = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.IndexOf('(') > -1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error with that line.

Comment: @Jake updated my answer. It doesn't like the period. Remove it too or use double.Parse() if you want to leave it in

Comment: This is good but depending on what else needs to be done with the value, this might be over kill. If there are other operations needed to be done with the value then I would go this way.

Comment: I replaced the original int CellValue line with the bool above, but then the if statements do not work because the criteria (>= 0 for example) do not work with a bool, so it says...

Comment: @Jake, you only need to check for true or false there is not >= anymore. If there is a ( then it's a negative number if not then it isn't. 0 is not a negative number.

Comment: @Jake: there is no need to parse the UI string. you can directly refer to bound value with DataBinder.Eval() and work with that value. If I am not missing anything, hopefully, my answer would help

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. If I will have a different currency symbol based on UI culture, this will entirely fail. All you need is DataItem go through DataBinder.Eval().

Comment: I have to agree, Priyank's solution is the correct way to do this

Comment: I have Priyank's in there now.  The other solutions worked well too, but I understand what y'all are saying about UI culture.  So Priyank, I have used your solution, but like the others, it breaks my Export to Excel (probably something to do with the databind that I don't understand)...my not understanding is a theme